# how might I manage exceptions thrown by another class

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I have a web form that accepts a user login - password, email. I then invoke an authorisation class which tests the fields, throwing an exception where applicable. My question is: In my code behind page, how should I manage/consume these exceptions?

Authorization class - Email property

```
        public string Email
    {
        get { return _email; }
        set 
        {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Email", "The email address is null");
            if (value == string.Empty)
                throw new ArgumentException("Email", "No email has been entered");
            if (!IsValidEmail(value))
                throw new ArgumentException("Email", "This is an invalid email address");
            _email = value; 
        }
    }
```

Code behind page - some sort of check

```
if (auth.Login(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text) == true) //or whatever the invokation might be
// do somehting with exceptions???
```

At this point I have no idea what I'm supposed to do with the exceptions the Authorisation class generates.

Comment: Minor nit, your `ArgumentException` has the message and parameter name backwards.

Comment: Should it not be parameter, message?

Comment: Confusingly enough, `ArgumentNullException` takes `parameter` then `message`. `ArgumentException` takes `message` then `parameter`. Please read the MSDN documentation for more information.

Comment: Those crazy guys at microsoft!

Comment: minor remark, instead of doing all these inside the seter you can have the required properties in your c'tor and check if string.IsNullOrEmpty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try
{
    auth.Login(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
}
catch (ArgumentException e)
{
    //Handle Exception here
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "EMail invalid");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be also doing client-side validation that the `txtUserName.Text` and `txtPassword.Text` fields are not empty.

As for the exceptions, you should have a global handler that provides a nice error message to the user if an exception is thrown (that is, if client-side validation failed to catch something and the server threw an exception). You should not need to catch individual exceptions on the client.

Comment: So would this be something in the code behind that exposes my exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch the exception, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to catch an `ArgumentException` -- that's one kind of exception that's a programming error, not a run-time exception. (The code should throw a `FormatException` if the user's input is invalid, for instance.)

Comment: That's interesting. Didn't realise that. Thanks.

Comment: The only scenario I would imagine where it's valid to do this is if the code you're calling incorrectly uses these exceptions and it's beyond your control; in that case, I'd personally do a try-catch to catch the ArgumentException, re-throw another FormatException (or some other kind), and catch that outside the body wherever it needs to be, so as to not break the design with the rest of the code. (Efficiency isn't an issue, because exceptions are always inefficient anyway.)

Comment: This may sound terrible but - If I'm using a try catch in the calling class that deals with the ArgumentExceptions thrown by the authorisation class,  what's the point changing it to FormatException if it works fine with ArgumentExceptions?

Comment: It's a great question, nothing terrible about it. :) It's not an ideal solution, but the point of it is that an `ArgumentException` *means* that the exception was a programming error, and you might also potentially catch *other* `ArgumentException`s that weren't meant to be caught. If you do the conversion ASAP, then you won't mix user errors with programming errors, and the program will be more readable and you'll be able to debug it more easily (since you won't mistakenly catch other exceptions). (If a `FormatException` doesn't make sense though, you might just have to leave it alone.)

Comment: @Lambert: Personally, I'd be inclined to avoid most of the predefined exceptions since they provide no information about the state of the system.  IMHO, a better exception hierarchy would start with ActionNotTakenException, ObjectCorruptException, ContainingObjectCorruptException, ThreadCorruptException, and SystemCorruptException and derive from those.  Knowing the state of objects and the system is generally more important than knowing what happened.  I agree with the philosophy of catching exceptions and wrapping them to better clarify what's really happening, but there are dangers.

Comment: @Lambert: Too bad there's no way in C# to exclude certain exceptions from being caught, while catching the base-type exceptions (one can catch and rethrow, but the semantics of that are different).

Comment: @Supercat: That's an interesting approach; I haven't used it before but it seems useful. The only downside is that you'd need to define all those exceptions yourself, and expect your callers to be aware of them... which is sometimes possible and sometimes not. But why do you say there are "dangers" in re-wrapping exceptions?

Comment: @Lambert: The danger of rewrapping exceptions is that a more serious exception might get disguised as a less serious one.  For example, code uses MyDatabaseWrapper.LoadRecord to load a record from a database; that in turn calls SuperDatabase.ProcessCommand, which throws SuperDatabaseServerIsMeltingDownException.  MyDataBaseWrapper catches this, doesn't realize it indicates a severe problem, and throws it as an ActionNotTakenException.  That in turn percolates back to the user as "Record not found", while the system continues using the bad database.

Comment: @Lambert: If there were a well-defined hierarchy of exceptions and rules related to escalating and de-escalating them, the dangers would be mininal, but since there is no hierarchy there's really no way of knowing whether an exception should be considered severe or not.

Comment: @Supercat: Oh ok, I'd never thought about this, but I see what you mean. Interesting, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Lambert - If you have some base exceptions as in your database example, rather than other classes reinterpreting the exceptions in their own way, can't the actual original exceptions just be reused/thrown by the calling class?

Comment: @hoakey: I believe you mean supercat's example, since I didn't mention databases myself. :)
I'm not sure what you mean... by the "calling class" and "other classes", did you mean the "calling method" and "other methods"? Sorry about this, I'm a little confused about what you mean.

Comment: @hoakey: A major difficulty comes when the precise type of the underlying class is unknown.  For example, class DbThingie might be designed to handle SqlServer, MySql, Access, and other SQL-implementing databases interchangeably, using a common interface.  If an interface wrapper is written for SuperDatabase database, and if the SuperDatabase throws an exception which the author of DbThingie never heard of, there's no way DbThingie will be able to do anything sensible with the exception.  On the other hand, if the person who writes the wrapper knows which errors are severe...

Comment: ... the wrapper can nest the exception in one of a small family of exceptions defined by the author of the interface.  If the database throws a SuperDatabaseRecordLockedException, the wrapper might rethrow as a DbWrapperRecordLockedException (the wrappers for SqlServer, Access, etc. would throw a DbWrapperRecordLockedException whenever they got a record-locked exception from their database)

Comment: @supercat - Yes that makes sense. Interestingly I came across the MS best practice on exceptions, and I'm in violation of one of their recommendations http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx The method you choose depends on how often you expect the event to occur. If the event is truly exceptional and is an error (such as an unexpected end-of-file), using exception handling is better because less code is executed in the normal case. If the event happens routinely, using the programmatic method to check for errors is better....

Comment: ..... In this case, if an exception occurs, the exception will take longer to handle. 
So with that said, I shouldn't even be throwing exceptions for things like password string.empty etc, but instead handle it programmatically

Comment: @hoakey: Code should avoid calling methods in a way that may cause them to throw exceptions, but code which cannot satisfy its caller's expected post-conditions should throw.  It's often good to allow a routine to be invoked two ways: assume normal behavior and throw if it doesn't work, or expect possible abnormal behavior and return an error code.  If the calling code isn't expecting an error, the called code should throw an exception if one arises.  If the called code is expecting an error, it's better to indicate it via an error flag.

Comment: @hoakey: One approach I've not seen used with .net, but which was rather nice in Turbo Pascal, was the use of an optional ByRef status variable.  If included, it would indicate whether an operation succeeded; if not included, a failing operation would trigger an IO error (typically crashing the program).  IMHO, that approach would be cleaner than having separate try/do syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You would need something like this:

```
try {
   auth.Login(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
}catch(ArgumentNullException anex){
   //output the message to the user
}catch(ArgumentException aex){
   //output the message to the user
}
```

You would need to catch every type of exception that you throw (or catch just `Exception`).

Comment: Would I not be able to use the exceptions generated in the authorization class?

Comment: what do you mean?  any exceptions thrown by the authorization class when auth.Login is called will be caught by the block above.  However, if you call auth.Login in many places, you would need the same block many times in order to have the same output.  If you have a try/catch that handles exceptions for the entire application, you can throw exceptions whereever you want and then that try/catch will display them in the same way no matter what.

Comment: Having a try catch for the entire app then sounds the way forward. How would that actually work? Would there be a try catch with a class of its own?

Answer (score 1):

Typically your application needs to react to these exceptions as they represent a specific state.  Reacting could be reporting (logging) the exceptions where applicable, redirecting the user to an error page, or providing a response related to the context of the exception (e.g. is this an exception due to invalid input data, if so, display the form with error messages, etc.).

Comment: In the authorization class thats what I've aimed to do. It's how I then bubble these exceptions up to the calling class e.g. the web form, and make use of them.

Answer (score 1):

I would publicly expose `IsValidEmail` and have a check prior to calling the login method. Then you could present the error prior to submission.